# Error making tuple containing a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a function `func` that returns an `std::tuple` of an `std::unique_ptr<A>` and a `double`. However, when I try to create the tuple I receive errors. The code follows:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    A() : data (3){}
private:
    double data;
};

std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<A>, double> func(double num) {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<A>();
    std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<A>, double> temp = std::make_tuple(a, num); // ERROR MESSAGE C
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

This code produces the following 4 errors in Visual Studio.

Error message A:

```
tuple(827,18): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to '_Ttype'
```

Error message B:

```
tuple(825,83): message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Error message C:

```
Source.cpp(14): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<A>>,double> std::make_tuple<std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<A>>&,double&>(std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<A>> &,double &)' being compiled
```

Error message D:

```
tuple(827,12): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
```

First, what is the cause of this error? Second, is the `A` associated with `a` being placed on the heap?

Comment: I think the problem is that you have to explicitly indicate that you're passing `unique_ptr` ownership over when you pass it in to a function as an argument. If you change the indicated line to `... = std::make_tuple(std::move(a), num);`, it compiles and works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable.  You are attempting to copy a `std::unique_ptr` to the tuple, and that will not work.  The compiler error message is kind of cryptic, IMO, but that is basically what seems to be the problem.

However, a `std::unique_ptr` is moveable, thus you can use `std::move`:

`std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<A>, double> temp = std::make_tuple(std::move(a), num);`